# Route Parameters not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a problem with route parameters in laravel, 
Here is the main.blade.php :

```
    <body>
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title m-b-md">
            Generate Your Domain Now
        </div>
        {!! Form::open(['route'=>'generatorindex' , 'method' => 'post']) !!}
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
            <input name="inputkeyword" type="text" placeholder="Enter your keyword">
            <button type="submit" value="Generate"></button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is the function in controller :

```
public function generator(Request $inputkeyword)
    {
        echo $productname = $inputkeyword->input('inputkeyword');

    }
```

finally, here is the route :

```
Route::any('/generator/{inputkeyword}', [ 'as' => 'generatorindex', 'uses' => 'MainController@generator' ]);
```

but it returns :

```
    ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: generatorindex] [URI: generator/{inputkeyword}]. (View: C:\Users\Mostafa\myapp\resources\views\main.blade.php)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Where should I define inputkeyword parameter ?

Comment: See in route you have defined /generator/{inputkeyword} like this but in form submission you are passing only generatorindex so please send the generatorindex/paremeter{id}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Generate Your Domain Now
            </div>
            {!! Form::open(['route'=> ['generatorindex', '??'] , 'method' => 'post']) !!}
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
                <input name="inputkeyword" type="text" placeholder="Enter your keyword">
                <button type="submit" value="Generate"></button>
            {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Either pass some value where I have written "??" in above code

OR

Make inputkeyword parameter optional by suffixing
 it with "?" into route.php file like this:

```
Route::any('/generator/{inputkeyword?}', [ 'as' => 'generatorindex', 'uses' => 'MainController@generator' ]);
```

Please read this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

---

**EDIT**

As per your requirement you told me in chat:

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('generator', [ 'as' => 'generatorindex', 'uses' => 'MainController@generator' ]);

Route::get('generator/{inputkeyword}', [ 'as' => 'generatorindexurl', 'uses' => 'MainController@generatorindexurl' ]);
```

**MainController.php**

```
public function generator() {
   return redirect()->route('generatorindexurl', request('inputkeyword'));
}

public function generatorindexurl()
{
   dd(request());
}
```

**view**

```
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Generate Your Domain Now
            </div>
            {!! Form::open(['route'=> ['generatorindex'] , 'method' => 'post']) !!}
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
                <input name="inputkeyword" type="text" placeholder="Enter your keyword">
                <button type="submit" value="Generate"></button>
            {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: should I use something like `['generatorindex', $inputkeyword->inputkeyword]`

Comment: Now it says Undefined variable: inputkeyword

Comment: First make sure that $inputkeyword->inputkeyword has some value assigned

Comment: Where should I pass the value to it ? in the controller file or in view file ?

Comment: I want it to generate a new url with user submitted keyword in form. 
for example, localhost:8000/generator/keyword1, or localhost:8000/generator/keyword2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135944/discussion-between-parth-vora-and-m-safari).

Comment: Why? You use 'method' => 'POST', set parameter to route have no sense.

Comment: Anytime, glad to help.